# Error when fetching IdentityUser data from Azure database

Tags: entity-framework, azure

Before publishing my project to Azure App Service, I executed code-first migration in Visual Studio without any seed data. 6 tables were created:

1. `dbo._MigrationHistory`
2. `dbo.AspNetRoles`
3. `dbo.AspNetUserClaims`
4. `dbo.AspNetUserLogins`
5. `dbo.AspNetUserRoles`
6. `dbo.AspNetUsers`

When I try to find if certain `IdentityUser` is registered by sending a request to my controller, I encounter the following error:

```
2016-04-16T09:58:30  PID[6608] Error
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1.IsIdentityV1Schema(DbContext db)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString, Boolean throwIfV1Schema)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at authentication.Contexts.AuthContext..ctor() in d:\Projects\learnAuth\authentication\Contexts\AuthContext.cs:line 7
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<FindAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

Connection string in `Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:seraphtest.database.windows.net,1433;Database=learnauth;User ID=seraph@seraphtest;Password=XXXXXXXX;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

`AuthContext.cs`:

```
public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public AuthContext() : base("AuthContext") { }
}
```

The source of error:

```
private UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;

public async Task<IdentityUser> Find(UserLoginInfo loginInfo)
{
    // stack trace starts from here
    IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(loginInfo);
    return user;
}
```

What is the source of this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: how do you get your connection string?

Comment: Copied from Azure Portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be working if I change the connection string from

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:seraphtest.database.windows.net,1433;Database=learnauth;User ID=seraph@seraphtest;Password=XXXXXXXX;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

to

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:seraphtest.database.secure.windows.net,1433;Database=learnauth;User ID=seraph@seraphtest;Password=XXXXXXXX;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```